# How can I have the nav menu, going out of the navbar, and not overlay it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, responsive

I've spent already 4h on trying to solve this one, but I just give up.
I'm trying to make an responsive menu, but when I press on hamburger menu, I would like my menu to drop down under the navbar, not on top of it, as you can see on the snippet.

```
<body>
    <nav class="nav">
      <img src="./img/logo.png" class="nav__logo" alt=" logo." />
      <ul class="nav__menu">
        <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">link1</a></li>
        <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">link2</a></li>
        <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">link3</a></li>
        <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">link4</a></li>
        <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">link5</a></li>
        <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">link6</a></li>
        <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">link7</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="hamburger__menu">
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
      </div>
    </nav>
    

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
```

```
.nav {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  max-height: 10vh;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: #fff;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: center;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04) 0px 3px 5px;
  z-index: 5;
}

.nav__logo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  align-self: center;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.nav__menu {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  align-self: center;
  gap: 2rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  align-items: center;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

ul {
  padding-left: 0;
}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.hamburger__menu {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  align-self: center;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.bar {
  display: block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  background-color: black;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .hamburger__menu {
    display: block;
  }

  .hamburger__menu.active .bar:nth-child(2) {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .hamburger__menu.active .bar:nth-child(1) {
    transform: translateY(8px) rotate(45deg);
  }
  .hamburger__menu.active .bar:nth-child(3) {
    transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
  }


  .nav__menu {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0%;
    top: -100%; 
    gap: 0;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: rgba(33, 35, 38, 0.1) 0px 10px 10px -10px;  
    border: 1px solid green;
    z-index: 1;
  }


  .nav__item {
    margin: 16px 0;
  }

  .nav__menu.active {
    top: 7.5%;
    transition: top 1s;
  }
}
```

```
const hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger__menu");
const navMenu = document.querySelector(".nav__menu");

hamburger.addEventListener("click", function () {
  hamburger.classList.toggle("active");
  navMenu.classList.toggle("active");
});

document.querySelectorAll(".nav__link").forEach((n) =>
  n.addEventListener("click", () => {
    hamburger.classList.remove("active");
    navMenu.classList.remove("active");
  })
);
```

```js
"use strict";

const hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger__menu");
const navMenu = document.querySelector(".nav__menu");

hamburger.addEventListener("click", function() {
  hamburger.classList.toggle("active");
  navMenu.classList.toggle("active");
});

document.querySelectorAll(".nav__link").forEach((n) =>
  n.addEventListener("click", () => {
    hamburger.classList.remove("active");
    navMenu.classList.remove("active");
  })
);
```

```css
.nav {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  max-height: 10vh;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: #fff;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: center;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04) 0px 3px 5px;
  z-index: 5;
}

.nav__logo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  align-self: center;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.nav__menu {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  align-self: center;
  gap: 2rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  align-items: center;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

ul {
  padding-left: 0;
}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.hamburger__menu {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  align-self: center;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.bar {
  display: block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  background-color: black;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .hamburger__menu {
    display: block;
  }
  .hamburger__menu.active .bar:nth-child(2) {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .hamburger__menu.active .bar:nth-child(1) {
    transform: translateY(8px) rotate(45deg);
  }
  .hamburger__menu.active .bar:nth-child(3) {
    transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
  }
  .nav__menu {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0%;
    top: -100%;
    gap: 0;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: rgba(33, 35, 38, 0.1) 0px 10px 10px -10px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .nav__item {
    margin: 16px 0;
  }
  .nav__menu.active {
    top: 7.5%;
    transition: top 1s;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav class="nav">
    <img src="./img/logo.png" class="nav__logo" alt="logo." />
    <ul class="nav__menu">
      <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">link1</a></li>
      <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">link2</a></li>
      <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">link3</a></li>
      <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">link4</a></li>
      <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">link5</a></li>
      <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">link6</a></li>
      <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">link7</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="hamburger__menu">
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
    </div>
  </nav>

</body>
```

I've tried to do it with z-index, but if i'll add a negative z-index on the menu, then I can't click the links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it can be done until the styles of nav and ul become siblings. Also you are trying to set z-index on statically positioned element, which does not take effect.

Comment: Glad to help. I did also ask another person and was told that they don't also don't think it's possible so this might be the solution. If you feel like this is was the correct answer, you can also tag it as such.

Answer (score 0):

Change the z-index value from 1 to -1

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  ...
  
  .nav__menu {
    ...
    z-index: -1;
  }
  
  ...
}
```

Comment: I’ve tried already, the links won’t work anymore…

Comment: Okay I see, so you can try to change the sibling between the ul and nav elements or you can also add a second ul element for the mobile menu outside the nav element.

Comment: Please beware of making duplicate HTML for phone while just hiding the one for desktop. It's bad for accessibility, SEO and code maintenance.